# jQuery toggleClass not working in chrome (jQuery 2.1.0)

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 2.1.0 on a project, and I have some wierd problem with `toogleClass()`, here are my code:

```
$('.options-item-label').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('option-opend');
});
```

A demo on jsfiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x3a32/1/)

It doesn't works on chrome, but works on my iPad, is there anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: is this in a dom ready state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such situations you should better bind event listener to checkbox itself to prevent double click event:

```
$('.options-item-label').on('click', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).toggleClass('option-opend');
});
```

The reason why it happens is simple. Label sort of generates one more event for corresponding input element. Since jQuery `on` method binds an event in bubbling phase, when the second "virtual" event propagates up from the checkbox to the label, it triggers your event handler one more time. Hence the issue.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x3a32/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can see from this demo that when you click the label, a click event is also fired for the input. So two click events are caught by your handler and the color gets toggled twice, ending up where you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/C2Kh4/

You can also see that the handler is called when you click to the right of the div, so the background can toggle without the input's status changing. I would instead bind the handler to the input itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/zvW8d/

```
$('.options-item-label input').on('change', function(e){
    $(this).closest('.options-item-label').toggleClass('option-opend', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, now I knew why it don't work, and thanks a lot for your demo :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, `return false`, this just works for me

```
$('.options-item-label').on('click', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('option-opend');
   return false;
});
```